# Remove a specific vertex and all its edges using native raw implementation

Tags: orientdb

Hello I am a new user of OrientDB and its java api. I use the Native raw implementation of the GrapDatabase because I want maximum performance.

How do I remove a specific vertex and all its edges with the OrientDB SQL?

Lets say the vertex has a field uid and I want to remove the vertex with uid 12 and all its edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a command like: "delete vertex where uid = 12". Stay tuned, we're working to the new API that it's much faster!